# Loading number formats for an EXCEL range

Tags: c#, excel

I know it is possible load a range of cell data into a system array in C#.

For Example:

```
  Excel.Range r1 = ws.get_Range("A1", "Q55");
  Array dataflds = (Array)r1.Cells.Value2;
```

Is there a way to do the same with the number formats for each cell in that range?  Inspecting them one at a time is very slow.  My attempts yield an error stating that you can not convert a string to a system array.